# Описание функции в с++. template<typename T> type Class<T>::function(). Можно ли как то сделать так чтобы при определении постоянно не писать template

Tags: c++, функции, шаблоны-с++

это заголовок: Collection.h

```
template <typename T>
class Collection{
purblic:
 void clear();
 void add(T value);
}
```

А это исходник: Collection.cpp

```
#include "Collection.h"

template<typename T> //здесь
void Collection<T>::clear()
{
    while (head != nullptr) {
        remove(0);
    }
}

template<typename T> //и тут и так далее
void Collection<T>::add(T value)
{
}
```

Я вот не понимаю почему при определении метода постоянно нужно указывать *template< typename T>*.
Можно ли как то один раз указать в .срр файле template< typename T> или определить функцию через просто имя класса?

Условно говоря нельзя ли сделать что-то типа такого:

```
template <typename T> Collection<T>::{
  void clear(){
    //Определение
        }
 void add(){
    //Определение
    }
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/495021/6944845. Нельзя, только макросами, иначе нужен новый синтаксис для указания, что это шаблон. По примерно тем же причинам, почему нужны "лишние" `typename` и `template` — https://stackoverflow.com/a/613132/6944845.

Comment: Более того, если вы определяете шаблоны функций в cpp-файле, то вызвать их можно будет только из этого же файла.

Comment: Интересно, что желания при определении членов класса "один раз указать в .cpp имя класса" не возникает... "*почему при определении метода постоянно нужно указывать `template< typename T>`*" — потому что таков синтаксис.

Comment: Вам все равно придется сдвинуть определения в хедер. А тогда их уже не обязательно выносить из класса.

Comment: потому-что тип `T` - это аргумент. Их может быть много, и они могут иметь имена любые на ваш вкус. Когда вы объявляете функцию с аргументами, то вы тоже пишете аргументы, имена и типы.

Comment: Тут стоило бы пояснить, что `Collection` - это не имя класса, а имя шаблона, а чтоб оно превратилось в класс, надо еще добавить параметр шаблона `CircleDoubleList<T>`, а чтобы иметь возможность это сделать, придется еще объявить параметр шаблона `template<typename T>`. Ну и плодить .cpp файлы - дурная привычка